# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not found - CentOS

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I am trying to run the following two commands...

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH =/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
>   export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH

But when I run the first command I get an error

```
-bash: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: command not found
```

My OS data is below,

> - OS Version                = CentOS release 5.9 (Final)
> - Platform Data             = 2.6.18-348.18.1.el5 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've tried as a normal user and as sudo, also get the same error when trying to just set LIBRARY_PATH.  This works on ubuntu what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Am seeing a space there???

Comment: @uprego may as well post that as an answer, just point out that there should be no space between the variable name and the `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is needed to wipe the space before the equal glyph (the `=`) to get the environment variable set.

Comment: et tu spacebar?  Thanks working now.

Comment: And btw if you put the space **after** the equal glyph, you _unset_ (am not sure about the inside mechanics) that variable.

Comment: And then you make the command interpreter try to run `/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1`, what _looks like a symlink to a shared object file_.